# How to hide Facebook chat boxes on Window resize?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-chat

I'm trying to reproduce in Jquery, how Facebook hide or show opened chat boxes when the viewport size changes.  Basically, if you have 6 chat windows open, and if you resize or shrink your browser, some of the chat windows are hidden if visually the 6 can't fix the screen size.

I'm using the function $(window).resize() to detect if the total width of all open windows plus some margin is greater than the window's width, then hide the first chat window, or show the last one if there's space for more windows.  Basic pop or push to stack...

My method isn't working because whenever resize runs, my script is constantly trying to hide or show the windows... (See code below)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

`ChatWidget.isEnoughRoom = function() {`

return ($(window).width() > ((ChatWidget.WINDOW_WIDTH * $('.chatWindowWidget:visible').length) + ChatWidget.CONTACTLIST_WIDTH + 100));

};

$(window).resize(function(){

```
    if(!ChatWidget.isEnoughRoom()) {
            $('.chatWindow:visible:last').hide() ;
    } else {
        $('.chatWindow:hidden:last').show() ;
    }
```

})

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Provide the code?

Comment: Window_Width being 240px and contactlist_width is 200px.  Basically adding the total width of all visible windows plus the contact list window with 100px margin.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seams to be related with the multiple triggering of resize function every time you resize the window. I tested in chrome and it triggered twice.
Give this a try:
https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize

Comment: Great suggestion! It works at hiding or showing 1 chat window at a time but if I resize the viewport really fast to a very large or small size, then it will not reduce or increase the number of windows appropriately... I have rewrite my function to show the right amount of boxes with the final window size.

Comment: Try to use timeouts to wait for the resize and take the width. In chrome is curious, on rezise the window take 2 widths, one of 1px and the other of the real width. This seams to be a problem not of jQuery but the javascript function that do the job.

Comment: Please if the answer served you accept it as a solution, i think you can't vote up yet. We all love to get some points here =)

Comment: I mean, in stackoverflow when you ask a question and someone answer a good solution you can accept that solution as the response of your question and that give some points to the user that give the solution. This fantastic site work with scores to give some kind of status to it's users. =)